# I have a problem with NullReferenceException in Unity. Can someone help me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started using Unity and i have a problem with this code. I followed a youtube tutorial and i copied this code but for some reason it doesn't work and it gives me this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Player.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Player.cs:28) Any help will be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Vector3 moveDelta;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;

    private void start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDelta = new Vector3(x,y,0);

        if (moveDelta.x > 0)
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        else if (moveDelta.x < 0)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);

        hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(0,moveDelta.y), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking","Actor"));
        if(hit.collider == null)
        {
           transform.Translate(0, moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(moveDelta.x,0), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking","Actor"));
        if(hit.collider == null)
        {
           transform.Translate(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `Player.FixedUpdate();` somewhere in your code,  I suspect the object `Player` is null when you call that `FixedUpdate()` method on it. Showing the code around that might be helpful.

Comment: @Mandivamba as mentioned also below in the comments the built-in messages like [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) get Invoked by the Unity engine itself ... This is a **typo** and it has to be [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) not `start` otherwise it will never be called by Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Start method name first letter must be capital

```
private void Start()
{
    boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}
```

Comment: If this is truly the answer, the post should be closed as a typo.

Comment: I would be amazed if this is the answer, you would get a not implemented error if the method is not properly inherited from MonoBehaviour, would not build. Fix the method name anyway.

The Player Object is probably null, need to new it up or inject it. or whatever so its not null when the method is called.

Comment: @Mandivamba no that is not how `MonoBehaviour` works in Unity! **None** of them are implemented at all, otherwise you would need to `override` them btw. No this is rather a pure **typo** since as also well known and documented these **message** methods get invoked by Unity's Message System and therefore have to exactly match the name and signature, otherwise they are simply never called

Comment: [**Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: Thank @derHugo wasn't familiar with that.